# How to remove a value mapped to a key when a key has multiple values mapped to it in a concurrent hash map?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am new to concurrent hash maps and I was wondering if I could get some guidance on the `.remove(key)` method.

If I have a concurrent hash map that has 1 key but several mapped values to that key, how do I go about removing that value associated with the key but not remove the key and other values associated with the key?

If I have something like:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> userValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value1);
   userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value2);
   userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value3);
   userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value4);
```

and I print out my map I get an output along the lines of:

```
{user=[value1, value2, value3, value4]}
```

And I want to do something along the lines of `userValues.remove(value1)` to have a new output of `{user=[value2, value3, value4]}`

How do I correctly and thread-safely do what I want in the code above?

Comment: In any map each key is associated with one and only one value object. The value object itself can be collection or composite, or both.

Comment: `userValues.get(key).remove(value1)`, because you want to remove the `value1` from the list associated to the key.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ArrayList` won't be thread-safe. You can switch the mapping function to `key -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> userValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Function<? super String, ? extends List<String>> mappingFunction = key -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, mappingFunction).add(value1);
userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, mappingFunction).add(value2);
userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, mappingFunction).add(value3);
userValues.computeIfAbsent(user, mappingFunction).add(value4);

userValues.get(user).remove(value3);
=>
userValues ==> {user=[value1, value2, value4]}
```

There are other thread-safe List implementations you could consider such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is threadsafe though ugly.
Check javadocs for `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent` and `compute`!

```
   userValues.compute(user, (k, v) -> {
     if (v == null) v = new ArrayList<>();
     v.add(value1);
     return v;})

   userValues.computeIfPresent(user, (k, v) -> {v.remove(value1); return v;})
```